# create a link with clicklistener on drawText

Tags: java, android

I try to add a link to my credits screen in my app [Roboyard](https://github.com/rubo77/Roboyard) that opens in the Browser

this is my RenderManager.java:

```
package roboyard.eclabs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;

public class RenderManager {
    private Canvas target, mainTarget;
    private final Paint brush;
    private final Resources resources;
    private final SparseArray<Drawable> resourceMap;
    private final Random random;

    public RenderManager(Resources resources){
        this.target = null;
        this.brush = new Paint();
        this.brush.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.resources = resources;
        this.resourceMap = new SparseArray<>();
        this.random = new Random();
    }

...

    public void drawText(int x, int y, String str){
        this.target.drawText(str, x, y, this.brush);
    }

    public void drawClickableText(int x, int y, String text, int color, int textSize, ClickListener clickListener) {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        brush.setColor(color);
        brush.setTextSize(textSize);
        brush.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        target.drawText(text, x, y + bounds.height() - textSize, brush);
        clickListener.setClickableBounds(x, y, x + bounds.width(), y + bounds.height());
    }

    public void handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, ClickListener clickListener) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (clickListener != null && clickListener.isClickable() && clickListener.isInsideClickableBounds(x, y)) {
                    clickListener.onClick();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick();
        void setClickableBounds(float left, float top, float right, float bottom);
        boolean isInsideClickableBounds(float x, float y);
        boolean isClickable();
    }
}
```

and this is my CreditsGameScreen.java:

```
package roboyard.eclabs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.graphics.Color;

/**
 * Represents the Credits game screen.
 * Created by Pierre on 04/02/2015.
 */
public class CreditsGameScreen extends GameScreen {

    public CreditsGameScreen(GameManager gameManager) {
        super(gameManager);
    }

    int hs2; // Half the screen height

    /**
     * Creates game objects for the Credits screen.
     */
    @Override
    public void create() {
        int ws2 = this.gameManager.getScreenWidth() / 2;
        hs2 = this.gameManager.getScreenHeight() / 2;
        // Add back button
        this.instances.add(new GameButtonGoto(7 * ws2 / 4 - 128, 9 * hs2 / 5 - 128, 128, 128, R.drawable.bt_back_up, R.drawable.bt_back_down, 0));
    }

    /**
     * Loads assets for rendering.
     *
     * @param renderManager The render manager
     */
    @Override
    public void load(RenderManager renderManager) {
        super.load(renderManager);
    }

    /**
     * Renders the Credits screen.
     *
     * @param renderManager The render manager
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(RenderManager renderManager) {
        // Get app version information
        int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
        String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;

        // Set background color
        //renderManager.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderManager.setColor(Color.parseColor("#B0CC99")); // Light green background
        renderManager.paintScreen();

        // Set text color and size
        renderManager.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        int ts = hs2 / 10; // Text size

        // Draw credits text
        renderManager.setTextSize((int) (1.2 * ts));
        renderManager.drawText(10, 2 * ts, "Created by");
        renderManager.setTextSize((int) (0.7 * ts));
        renderManager.drawText(10, 3 * ts, "Alain Caillaud");
        renderManager.drawText(10, 4 * ts, "Pierre Michel");
        renderManager.drawText(10, 5 * ts, "Ruben Barkow-Kuder");

        renderManager.setTextSize((int) (1.2 * ts));
        renderManager.drawText(10, 7 * ts, "Based on");
        renderManager.setTextSize((int) (0.7 * ts));
        renderManager.drawText(10, 8 * ts, "Ricochet Robots(r)");

        renderManager.setTextSize((int) (1.2 * ts));
        renderManager.drawText(10, 10 * ts, "Imprint/privacy policy");
        renderManager.setTextSize((int) (0.7 * ts));
        drawClickableLink(renderManager, 10, 11 * ts, "https://eclabs.de/datenschutz.html");

        renderManager.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderManager.setTextSize((int) (1.2 * ts));
        renderManager.drawText(10, 13 * ts, "Open Source");

        drawClickableLink(renderManager, 10, 14 * ts, "https://git.io/fjs5H");

        renderManager.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderManager.drawText(10, 17 * ts, "Version: " + versionName + " (Build " + versionCode + ")");

        super.draw(renderManager);
    }

    /**
     * Draws a clickable link.
     *
     * @param renderManager The render manager
     * @param x             The x-coordinate of the link
     * @param y             The y-coordinate of the link
     * @param url           The URL of the link
     */
    private void drawClickableLink(RenderManager renderManager, int x, int y, String url) {
        renderManager.drawClickableText(x, y, url, Color.BLUE, (int) (0.7 * (hs2 / 10)), new RenderManager.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                openLink(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void setClickableBounds(float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
                // No need to assign values here
                // These bounds are set internally by the RenderManager
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isInsideClickableBounds(float x, float y) {
                // Check if the touch coordinates (x, y) are inside the clickable bounds
                // Not implemented in this snippet, but you would check the bounds here
                return true; // Placeholder return value
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isClickable() {
                // Determine if the text is clickable
                // Not implemented in this snippet, but you would handle the clickable state here
                return true; // Placeholder return value
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Opens a link in a web browser.
     *
     * @param url The URL to open
     */
    private void openLink(String url) {
        // Create an intent to open a web browser with the specified URL
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        // Start the activity (open the web browser)
        gameManager.getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the Credits screen.
     *
     * @param gameManager The game manager
     */
    @Override
    public void update(GameManager gameManager) {
        super.update(gameManager);
        // Handle back button press to return to the main menu
        if (gameManager.getInputManager().backOccurred()) {
            gameManager.setGameScreen(0); // Set the main menu screen
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cleans up resources used by the Credits screen.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy();
    }
}
```

The links appear and are blue, but still they are not clickable by touch

What am I missing?

Comment: You have never called `handleTouchEvent`

Comment: Where do I have to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man! You code is cool.

in CreditsGameScreen> inside overriden update method; I checked if the touch is within the text bounds.

```
@Override
    public void update(GameManager gameManager) {
        super.update(gameManager);
        InputManager im = gameManager.getInputManager();
        // Handle back button press to return to the main menu
        if (im.backOccurred()) {
            gameManager.setGameScreen(0); // Set the main menu screen
        } else if(im.eventHasOccurred()) {
            for (GameButtonLink link : links) {
                boolean linkTouched = (im.getTouchX() >= link.getX() && im.getTouchX() <= link.getW()) && (im.getTouchY() >= link.getY() && im.getTouchY() <= link.getH());
                if(linkTouched) {
                    openLink(link.getUrl());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the Result:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w7koJZhfapGDEr1xBIY63PyfW4uh9_QP/view?usp=sharing

You can also change the color of the link texts on ACTION_DOWN also to show users the tap effect.

Comment: Hi, Normally we override onTouchEvent when creating a custom view or setting a OnTouchListener. Clarify me one thing, in your scenario; does GameScreen extends any View? how are you able to use onDraw? then it would become more clear to debug.

Comment: I don't really know much about the concept. I continued maintaining foreign code. This is the source https://github.com/rubo77/Roboyard

Comment: I have edited the answer. Let me know if you got the idea where to put the click, also if you need then where to share the code. Here, on github or on email.

Comment: we could discuss this more in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256918/roboyard

Comment: Here's the PR link: https://github.com/Eastcoast-Laboratories/Roboyard/pull/17
I have made changes in 2 files: 1. RenderManager 2. CreditsGameScreen and added a new file GameButtonLink.  you can remove commented code or any other code you can modify on your accord.

Comment: I am just a beginner please don't judge those code changes. 

Comment: your code worked and is online. Version 12 will have your code in it. thanks a lot! Maybe you like to code some more. I still have some issues open on the GitHub roboyard. If you like, I could use some help there too. E.g. https://github.com/Eastcoast-Laboratories/Roboyard/issues/7

Comment: Glad to hear that..! I'll try to solve some other issues whenever I can. Thanks for the points.